# The devtools tool for vuejs doesn't work on windows, neither with chrome nor with firefox

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, devtools, voyager

The devtools tool for vuejs doesn't work on windows, neither with chrome nor with firefox. when inspecting, the vue tab does not appear, only sometimes (very hard). I am working with Laravel, Voyager and Vuejs. The tool does not appear in the two arrows either

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what could be going on? I can't move forward with my learning of vue without that tool. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it show without errors in the "Add-ons and Themes" page on Firefox? Have you made sure Vue is _not_ in production mode? Did you check [The Vue devtools don't show up](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/faq.html#the-vue-devtools-don-t-show-up) form their FAQ?

Comment: It should not appear in the sub-section (your second image, with the 2 arrows) anyway. Only in the section with `Security, Lighthouse` etc tbh. As of why, if you have the official latest devtools, it should work. If it doesn't, feel free to close your currently running browser tab, and open it again + toggle off/on the devtools. Then it should properly appear and should be ready to use. It's not really OS-dependant either.